# Get object id of document already in mongoDB collection in Python

Tags: python, django, templates, mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb in which I have already inserted the documents.Now I want to update a document entry and I want to retrieve the document ID in the django template,like I am using checkbox alongside of the entry in the HTML.I want to give individual box a unique id which i plan to use same as the document id  .. so **HOW DO I RETRIEVE THE DOCUMENT ID IN THE DJANGO TEMPLATE** ?

Comment: show some code on how are you trying to do this and where are stuck in particular. Remember StackOverflow is not a forum! See some FAQ here http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 7):

You can get the ID of a MongoDB document using the `_id` attribute. However using `{{ object._id }}` in a Django template, makes it throw an error saying it couldn't find the _id attribute.

To solve this, you must create a custom template tag for your app and use that to get the _id.

Inside your app folder, create a templatetags folder and create some python file eg:appname_tags.py.

The directory structure would be something like this

```
/projectdir
  /appdir
    /templatetags
      __init__.py
      appname_tags.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

Inside the appname_tags.py paste the following code

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter("mongo_id")
def mongo_id(value):
    return str(value['_id'])
```

Now you can use this new custom template tag in your templates by loading the tag module and passing the mongo document object to it.

```
<html>
 <body>
  {% load appname_tags %}
  <p>here is your mongodb record id: {{ object|mongo_id }}</>
 </body>
</html>
```

Remember, the app should be in the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings variable in `settings.py` for django to load the template tag.