# pymongo and use of ObjectId in page

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I fetch results from mongodb (with django&pymongo) and print it with cursor to web page.
result is returned like below within cursor

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('51ab6decf146ee76f5f87420'), u'krm': u'test entry'}
```

**Question:** 
How can I parse _id section of this cursor and use it in page as href variable

```
{% for list_of_krm in v_srch %}
    <li class="move">
    <a class="page" href="...????...">{{list_of_krm.krm}}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**SOLUTION:**
create templatetags folder inside app directory and then write below code with name get_oid.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter("o_id")
def o_id(value):
   return str(value['_id'])
```

load it inside of the html as below

```
{% load get_oid %}
```

then using below notation

```
<a class="page" href="{{list_of_krm|mongo_id}}">
```

will give this :`<a class="page" href="51ab6decf146ee76f5f87297">`

Comment: you can always write a templatetag to parse the string

Comment: mentioned also in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893873/get-object-id-of-document-already-in-mongodb-collection-in-python)