# django mongodb _id issue

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and Djongo.
I've imported an existing MongoDB with mongorestore and I can list all db content in a Django template.

What I want to do: make links to the detail view for each document displayed in the list.

I've followed the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893873/get-object-id-of-document-already-in-mongodb-collection-in-python) trying just to print the MongoDB _id value but get the **error**:

> string indices must be integers

These are my files:

Template **elenco_strutture.html**

```
{% load strutture_ricettive_tags %}

{% block content %}
  {% for struttura in strutture %}
      <div class="post">
          <div class="date">
              {{ struttura.loc }}
          </div>

          <h1>Mongo ID: {{ object|mongo_id }}</h1>
          <br>coord: {{ struttura.location|linebreaksbr }}
      </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**strutture_ricettive_tags.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter("mongo_id")
def mongo_id(value):
    return str(value['_id'])
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.elenco_strutture, name='elenco_strutture'),
    url(r'^struttura/(?P<mongo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.struttura_detail, name='struttura_detail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.

from .models import Strutture

def elenco_strutture(request):

    strutture = Strutture.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'strutture_ricettive/elenco_strutture.html', {'strutture': strutture})

def struttura_detail(request, _id):
    struttura = get_object_or_404(Struttura, mongo_id=mongo_id)
    return render(request, 'strutture_ricettive/struttura_detail.html', {'struttura': struttura})
```

**Traceback**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://alberghi-sicilia.vmware/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'strutture_ricettive']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/alberghi_sicilia/strutture_ricettive/templates/strutture_ricettive/base.html, error at line 8
   string indices must be integers
   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : <!doctype html>
   3 : <html>
   4 : <head>
   5 : <meta charset="utf-8">
   6 :         <title>Strutture Ricettive Sicilia</title>
   7 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   8 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxc dn.bootstrapcdn.com/b ootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   9 :         <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" "type=text/css">
   10 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
   11 :     </head>
   12 :     <body>
   13 :         <div class="page-header">
   14 :             <h1><a href="/">home</a></h1>
   15 :         </div>
   16 : 
   17 :         <div class="content container">
   18 :         <div class="row">


Traceback:

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/alberghi_sicilia/strutture_ricettive/views.py" in elenco_strutture
  15.     return render(request, 'strutture_ricettive/elenco_strutture.html', {'strutture': strutture})

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  993.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  703.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/var/www/django_virtualenv/progetti_django/alberghi_sicilia/strutture_ricettive/templatetags/strutture_ricettive_tags.py" in mongo_id
  6.     return str(value['_id'])

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You appear to be reading the post to literally. In your template that would be `{{ struttura|mongo_id }}`. The post used `object` as a general term for the "document" or dict.

Comment: @Neil Lunn: Thank you. Now, using: {{ struttura|mongo_id }} I get another error: 'Strutture' object is not subscriptable